# populate select options in select in knockout dynamically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout for rendering select dropdowns.
The second dropdown is populated when first changes.
The data store is as follows:

option1:{
a:"someval",
b:"someval"
},
option2:{
a:"someval",
b:"someval"
}

As you would've guessed, option1,option2 are options for primary dropdown
and secondary dropdown has options as a/b/c with their corresponding values.

I'm having trouble for updating/initialing options for second dropdown.
I'm confused how should i put populated the data in optionText and optionValues
Here's a snippet of my bindings.

```js
KOTAK :{
          EMIK12:"12_Months",
          EMIK18:"18_Months",
          EMIK24:"24_Months",
          EIK3:"3_Months",
          EMIK6:"6_Months",
          MIK9:"9_Months",
},
      INDUS : {
          EMIID12:"12_Months",
          EMIIND18:"18_Months",
          EMIIND24:"24_Months",
          EMIIND3:"3_Months",
          EMIIND36:"36_Months",
          EMIIND6:"6_Months",
          EMIIND9:"9_Months"
          
          },
```

```html
<select aria-required="true" type="text" data-bind = "optionsCaption : 'Select Bank..',options : ($data.bankList() && $data.bankList()[0].BANKS) ? $data.bankList()[0].BANKS : [],
                                                 event : {change : $data.onClickEmiOptions.bind(this)}"
                                     class="form-control"></select>
                                      
<select aria-required="true" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind = "optionsCaption : 'Select Duration',
                                             options : $data.selectedEmiOptions,optionsText:function(item){return item;},optionsValue:''">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one way of doing it

```js
function myViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.items = [{id: 1, name: 'Europe', times: [9,10,11,12]}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'America', times: [10,11,13]}];
  
  self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
  self.selectedTime = ko.observable(null);
  
  self.selectedItem.subscribe(function (item) {
   self.selectedTime(item.times[0]);
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedItem"></select>
<br />
<!-- ko with: selectedItem() -->
<select data-bind="options: times, value: $parent.selectedTime"></select>
<br />
<span data-bind="text: $parent.selectedItem().name"></span>
<br/>
<span data-bind="text: $parent.selectedTime"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```